# Django - Not passing id from template to views

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

In my ToDoApp, I couldn't send the ID to my function. Not sure what mistake I'm making.

Seems my function is correct because when I tested the form action with "datechange/1". It worked.

Here is my code:

Index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<h3 style = "margin-bottom: 20px"><strong>To Do List App</strong></h3>

<form method="POST" action="datechange/{{task.id}}">
    {%csrf_token%}
<ul class="list-group">
{% for task in tasklist %}


<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <input type='hidden' name = {{task.id}}>{{task.tasks}}
    <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">{{task.duedate}}
        <input type="date" name="datepick"/>
        <input type='submit' value = 'Update'>   
    </span>
</li>
{% endfor %}

</form>
```

Views.py

```
def index(request):
    tasklist = Task.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'tasklist':tasklist})

def datechange(request,id):
    # taskid = request.POST.get(id='task.id')
    # task = Task.objects.get(id=taskid)
    task = Task.objects.get(id=id)
    datepick = request.POST.get('datepick')
    task.duedate = datepick
    task.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

Urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.index,name='index'),
    path('datechange/<int:id>',views.datechange,name='datechange'),
]
```

[image: App Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use action in form like that, Django has a better behaviour for such simple forms. The view `datechange` is also not needed. Just put everything from that view into `if request.method == "POST"` like that:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        task_id = request.POST.get("task_id")
        task = Task.objects.get(id=task_id)
        datepick = request.POST.get('datepick')
        task.duedate = datepick
        task.save()
    tasklist = Task.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'tasklist':tasklist})
```

And delete action from your form in template:

```
<form method="POST">
    {%csrf_token%}
    <input type="hidden" name="task_id" value="{{ task.id }}">
    ...
```

Submitting the form will render index again, but also will process everything in `POST` you have inside that view. If you just open it (`GET` method) it will ignore that processing opening the view in a standard way.

Comment: Thanks. I made the changes. However, throwing this error now. ```TypeError at /
Field 'id' expected a number but got <built-in function id>.```

Comment: @Saassy Edit the question with what exact changes do you made, most probably you done a mistake while fetching task object, it must be `Task.objects.get(id=task_id)` not something else or use `get_object_or_404(Task, id=task_id)`

Comment: @Saassy you most likely left it like that: `task = Task.objects.get(id=id)` - check how I did it in my answer. Remember, that `id` is a built-in function, you should never use it as a variable.

Comment: It is working nowww